# C++ Common Base Pointer of All Classes Up-casted, Down-casted and Side-casted

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

I have a complex code with several levels of (multiple) inheritance. The algorithm is implemented (without documentation) directly in the code creating a web of dependencies. The basic concept is something like:

```
class Base;
class Interface;

class A : public Base, public Interface {
  std::vector<child*> children;

  A() {
    auto pbox = new child("Box")
    children.push_back(pbox);
    auto psquare = new child("Square")
    children.push_back(psquare);
    auto pcircle = new child("Circle");
    children.push_back(pcircle);

    global::edge(this, pbox);
    global::edge(this, psquare);
    global::edge(this, pcircle);
  }

  virtual void add_child( child * pchild ) {
    children.push_back(pchild);
    global::edge(this, pchild);
  }
```

I would like to discover the web of dependencies, by inserting static functions `global::edge` to map them.

However:

`this` will resolve differently depending on the cast:

- `dynamic_cast<A*>(this)`
- `dynamic_cast<Base*>(this)`
- `dynamic_cast<Interface*>(this)`

All three will have different values. Is there a way in c++ to cast a pointer to its most 'basic' form? That is to the value which was returned by `new`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is precisely the purpose of `dynamic_cast<void*>(this)`.
But since the language cannot statically know what the type will be, you can only get a `void*` back.

Comment: I would say "the compiler cannot know what type...". The programmer might know, in which case the programmer can `static_cast` this `void*` to that type. +1 for the correct code.